# React and Node Login implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, mern

I have an application in which i need to make auths
i made the exact replica of react-routers auth workflow(https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Auth.js

```
 const auth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(data, scb, fcb) {
  fetch("/api/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
 })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    scb();
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    fcb();
  });
  },
 signout(cb) {
   localStorage.removeItem("token");
  this.isAuthenticated = false;
  cb();
 },
  checkSignIn(cb, fcb) {
   fetch("api/user/me", {
   headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-auth-token": localStorage.token
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log("here");
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    cb();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("here in checksign in catch");
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    fcb();
  });
  }
};
export default auth;
```

Now while when the page loads i use checkSignIn method and redirect the user to dashboard if the user is authenticated

The main problem is if the token expires , my API call will be rejected , now i want to redirect the user back to Login , I use the signout method and pass the callback to change the state of the component and return  but the problem is I am seeing too much repetition in the code , at every api call i have to pass a callback to change the state of the page if the api call fails or i have to use withRouter (HOC) but i have to wrap my every component in that.
Is there any alternative way to implement this functionality

Comment: But the callback is always the same, right? (`if (userToken is expired) {logout user and send them back to home page}`) You could abstract all of your API calls through a common HTTP module or functon that always applies that test to every call. Then, no matter what API you are hitting, if your token expires, the wrapper will send the user where they need to go.

Comment: So I will make a module that will make all the API calls , but I think I have to provide repetitive callbacks when I call that function